# Ionic app shows : Cannot find module './getContents' when running ionic serve

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic framework. I am trying to run the Ionic app in my Windows system, but when I run `ionic serve` it shows the following error:

> Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
>
> Cannot find module './getContents'
>
> Do you need to run `npm install`?

I ran the command `npm install` and still have the same problem.

Here is my Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
    sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
    gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
        keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
    return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
        gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
    if (!sh.which('git')) {
        console.log(
            '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
            '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
            '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
            '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
        );
        process.exit(1);
    }
    done();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets of your gulpfile?

Comment: @damienc I added the gulp file please have a look